# Why is “Object” capitalized in the Declaration of Independence?

Tags: meaning, capitalization

> But when a long train of abuses and usurpations, pursuing invariably the same **Object** evinces a design to reduce them under absolute **Despotism**, it is their right, it is their duty, to throw off such Government, and to provide new **Guards** for their future security.

Thomas Jefferson

Why are the 3 bold words capitalized?